# ISSN format in c++, trouble with space, bool function, and array

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I am trying to return a Boolean function asking to enter a ISSN number, if it's the right format for a correct ISSN, it should return `true`, otherwise `false`.

Thing is, as you can see, the ISSN has to start with ISSN then 4 digits then - then another 4 digts. But, I'm having trouble dealing with the space between ISSN and the numbers**. Also, I was considering using `istringstream` to have the full ISSN back like : **ISSN 0395-2037****.

Here's my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<string>
#include<string.h>
#include <sstream> 
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string issn;
    string space;
    string arr[10];
    istringstream is("ISSN 0395-2037");
    is >> issn;
    is >> space;
    for (int i = 0; i < space.length(); i++)
    {
        arr[i] = space[i];
    }
    if (issn != "ISSN"
        and arr[4] != "-")
    {
        return false;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Should I stock it all in an array to make it easier to manipulate?

Thanks!

Comment: You don't need to read in the space. Streams already handle that. You can directly tackle the numbers.

Comment: I would typically opt for a regex match for stuff like this

Comment: @TrebuchetMS now im having trouble withe the "-" and i would need to convert numbers into int, but nothing else